# How to find the decrease value, when you know the amount of steps and the budget

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Forgive my ignorance in advance for this question as I'm not a mathematician in any respect. I can't even pretend to give correct terminology so I'll just give an example:

We are monitoring the amount of graffiti on buildings in a city during a period of 5 years. Every year we write down the total amount of graffiti murals. We start these measurements in 2021, and we measured 600 murals. Now we have a theoretical model how we want these murals to decline, see below table:

We want the murals to decline with 2% based on the year of 2021 every year. Meaning in the end an absolute total of 2880 murals in 5 years.

| year | murals | percentage decrease from base year | absolute decrease | cumulative |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | 600 | 2% | 12 | 600 |
| 2022 | 588 | 2% | 12 | 1188 |
| 2023 | 576 | 2% | 12 | 1764 |
| 2024 | 564 | 2% | 12 | 2328 |
| 2025 | 552 | 2% | 12 | 2880 |

Now we want to test this model in real life. The thing is; we want to act based on the maximum amount of murals in 5 years. This is the value of 2880.

We would like to use the following table to help us determine how we should act:

| year | actual measured murals | murals next year | decrease percentage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | 600 | 588 | 2% |
| 2022 | 610 |  |  |
| 2023 |  |  |  |
| 2024 |  |  |  |
| 2025 |  |  |  |

In this example we see that 2022 actually had 610 murals. I want to calculate the murals for next year.

- In 5 years the maximum of murals is 2880
- I want to have a percentage of decrease which is constant over the next years

How do I calculate this?